# pgfdeclareshape with variable dimensions using pgfkeys

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfkeys

I am trying to define some shapes for TikZ using \pgfdeclareshape. I would like to use options to make their size adjustable, however I do not get it to work. This example compiles, but the size of the circle is not set properly (or at all). What am I doing wrong :?

```
\documentclass[oneside,12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}


\makeatletter
\pgfkeys{/tikz/mycirclesize/.code={\pgf@x = #1}}
\pgfkeys{/tikz/mycirclesize/.default = 0.75cm}
\pgfkeysgetvalue{/tikz/mycirclesize}{\macro}

\pgfdeclareshape{mycircle}
{
    \savedanchor\centerpoint{
        \pgf@x = .5\wd\pgfnodeparttextbox
        \pgf@y = .5\ht\pgfnodeparttextbox
    }
    \anchor{center}{\centerpoint}

    \saveddimen\circsize{ \macro }


    \backgroundpath{
        \centerpoint

        \pgfkeys{/pgf/minimum size = \circsize}
        \pgfset{inner sep=1pt}
        \pgfnode{circle}{center}{}{}{\pgfusepath{draw}}
    }

}

\makeatother

\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}

    \draw (0,0) node[mycircle, mycirclesize=2cm] {};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is due to what `mycirclesize` does and when it does it.

You declare it with:

```
\pgfkeys{/tikz/mycirclesize/.code={\pgf@x = #1}}
\pgfkeys{/tikz/mycirclesize/.default = 0.75cm}
\pgfkeysgetvalue{/tikz/mycirclesize}{\macro}
```

This says three things:

1. When `\pgfkeys{/tikz/mycirclesize=<something>}` is called, execuite `\pgf@x=<something>` at that moment.
2. Set the default of `/tikz/mycirclesize` to `0.75cm` so that if `\pgfkeys{/tikz/mycirclsize}` is called, ie without an argument, we assume it to be `0.75cm`.
3. Get the **current value** of `/tikz/mycirclesize` and store it in `\macro`.

This third is crucial.  At this point, `/tikz/mycirclesize` *has no value* and what is returned is simply `\relax` (it hasn't even been initialised).  So `\macro` is let to be `\relax` and its value is frozen at this time.

Later, you call:

```
\draw (0,0) node[mycircle, mycirclesize=2cm] {};
```

which executes the key `/tikz/mycirclesize` with a value of `2cm` and this sets `\pgf@x` to `2cm` at that moment.  It then gets wiped out pretty soon as `\pgf@x` tends to get battered about from one thing to the next without so much as a by-your-leave.

What you probably want to do is store the argument to `mycirclesize` as its *value* and then in the `\savedimen` call inside the shape get this value (and assign it to `\pgf@x` as that's how `\savedimen` works).  The following is some code that will do that with minimal changes to your code.

```
\documentclass[oneside,12pt]{scrartcl}
%\url{http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/73877/86}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}


\makeatletter
\pgfkeys{/tikz/mycirclesize/.initial = 0.75cm}

\pgfdeclareshape{mycircle}
{
    \savedanchor\centerpoint{
        \pgf@x = .5\wd\pgfnodeparttextbox
        \pgf@y = .5\ht\pgfnodeparttextbox
    }
    \anchor{center}{\centerpoint}

    \saveddimen\circsize{\pgf@x=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/mycirclesize}}


    \backgroundpath{
        \centerpoint
        \pgfkeys{/pgf/minimum size = \circsize}
        \pgfset{inner sep=1pt}
        \pgfnode{circle}{center}{}{}{\pgfusepath{draw}}
    }

}

\makeatother

\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}

    \draw (0,0) node[mycircle, mycirclesize=2cm] {};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Wow, thanks for the fast reply. This works, and it works exactly as I want it to work =D
Anyway, I do not yet quite understand the difference in your and my implementation (or rather, why the difference leads to different behaviour), but I will try to figure that out.. Your explanation is extremely helpful.