# Adding extra nodes at anchors of rectangular node custom shape in tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to make a node which will be a SPDT switch symbol, which looks like this:

[image: spdt-orig.png]

So, I thought, I could start by deriving a custom shape from a rectangular node, whose size will be set by `minimum width/height`; then I could add small circular nodes at `south west`, `north west` and `east`, and draw a connector line with arrow from the `east`to the `north west` node. I would like the added nodes to be addressable (so I can use them later for connector lines); and I would also like to have a parameter for controlling the small circular nodes' size.

I tried reading:

- [Can a shape be composed out of "subshapes" in TikZ?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18400/can-a-shape-be-composed-out-of-subshapes-in-tikz)
- [How to draw saturation symbol inside a node in TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/65469/how-to-draw-saturation-symbol-inside-a-node-in-tikz)
- [pgfdeclareshape with variable dimensions using pgfkeys](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/73877/pgfdeclareshape-with-variable-dimensions-using-pgfkeys)

... and so I tried to cook up an example, but I get stuck at this point:

[image: test31.png]

The `X` and the rectangular border are added just for debug; it starts fine (I can draw a circle path, and also add a circular node at the same position, at `south west`), but then the problem is - it seems I cannot calculate the height of the master node properly for the `north west` "small" node.

What would be the right way to solve this? Also, the MWE below works for `above=of` positioning, but crashes for `right=of` positioning - any way to fix that?

Here is my MWE so far:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}

% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18400/can-a-shape-be-composed-out-of-subshapes-in-tikz
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/65469/how-to-draw-saturation-symbol-inside-a-node-in-tikz
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/73877/pgfdeclareshape-with-variable-dimensions-using-pgfkeys
\makeatletter
\pgfkeys{/tikz/spdtcircsize/.initial = 0.15cm}
\pgfdeclareshape{spdt}{
  %\savedanchor\centerpoint{
  %  \pgf@x = .5\wd\pgfnodeparttextbox
  %  \pgf@y = .5\ht\pgfnodeparttextbox
  %}
  %\anchor{center}{\centerpoint}
  \inheritsavedanchors[from={rectangle}]
  \inheritbackgroundpath[from={rectangle}]
  \inheritanchorborder[from={rectangle}]
  \foreach \x in {center,north east,north west,north,south,south east,south west}{
    \inheritanchor[from={rectangle}]{\x}
  }
  \saveddimen\circsize{\pgf@x=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/spdtcircsize}}
%   \savedanchor{\center}{%
%     \pgfpointorigin}
%   \anchor{center}{\center}
%%
%   \backgroundpath{
  \foregroundpath{
%     \centerpoint
%     \pgfkeys{/pgf/minimum size = \circsize}
%     \pgfset{inner sep=1pt}
%%
    \southwest
    \pgfpathcircle{\southwest}{\circsize}
%     \pgfusepath{draw}
    {
    \pgfkeys{/pgf/minimum size = \circsize}
    \pgftransformshift{\southwest}
    \pgfnode{circle}{center}{}{\tikz@fig@name-c1}{\pgfusepath{draw}}
    }
    %\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{0}{-\pgf@ya}}
    \pgfpointdiff{\northeast}{\southwest}
    \pgf@xa=\pgf@x \pgf@ya=\pgf@y
%     \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpointadd{\southwest}{\pgfpoint{0}{-1.0\pgf@ya}}}
    \pgfpathcircle{\pgfpointadd{\southwest}{\pgfpoint{0}{-1.0\pgf@ya}}}{\circsize}
%     \pgfnode{circle}{center}{}{\tikz@fig@name-c2}{}
  }
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw] (n1) at (1,0) {Testing};
% right= of causes ! Package PGF Math Error: Unknown function `west' (in 'west').
\node[spdt,draw,minimum width=20pt,minimum height=20pt] (n2) [above=10pt of n1] {X};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I think you are almost there. Add `east,west` anchors to the foreach.

Comment: Many thanks for the comment @percusse, very nicely spotted (that's what happens when I copypaste blindly `:)`). That fixes the `right=of` issue, but I still don't know how to use the height provided by `\pgfpointdiff` properly... Cheers!

Comment: First question: Do you want to include text inside the node?  If not, you can use a fixed size instead of messing with \pgfnodepartextbox.

Comment: Thanks for that, @JohnKormylo - I would like text more-less for debugging purposes (and maybe to set size), but those `\pgfnodepartextbox` are simply artefacts of copypasting of snippets... Cheers!

Comment: It was a stupid question.  If you are going to inherit the anchors from rectangle, you will want the switch to match.  I'm just more used to doing ciruitikz components, which have a fixed size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Final solution:  I moved the circles inside the boundary, created new anchors and drew the switch.  All those \pgfscope's really are needed.

[image: switch]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\newlength{\circsize}
\newlength{\spdtright}
\newlength{\spdtup}
\newlength{\spdtleft}
\newlength{\spdtdown}
\newlength{\spdtlen}

\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}

\pgfkeys{/tikz/spdtcircsize/.initial = 0.08cm}
\pgfdeclareshape{spdt}{
  \inheritsavedanchors[from={rectangle}]
  %\inheritbackgroundpath[from={rectangle}]
  \inheritanchorborder[from={rectangle}]
  \foreach \x in {center,text,north east,north west,north,south,south east,south west,east,west}{
    \inheritanchor[from={rectangle}]{\x}
  }
\anchor{out}{
  \pgfextractx{\spdtright}{\northeast}%
  \pgfextracty{\spdtup}{\northeast}%
  \pgfextracty{\spdtdown}{\southwest}%
  \pgfpoint{\spdtright}{0.5\spdtup+0.5\spdtdown}
 }
\anchor{off}{
  \circsize=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/spdtcircsize}%
  \pgfextractx{\spdtleft}{\southwest}%
    \pgfextracty{\spdtdown}{\southwest}%
    \pgfpoint{\spdtleft}{\spdtdown+\circsize}%
}
\anchor{on}{
  \circsize=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/spdtcircsize}%
  \pgfextracty{\spdtup}{\northeast}%
  \pgfextractx{\spdtleft}{\southwest}%
   \pgfpoint{\spdtleft}{\spdtup-\circsize}%
}
\foregroundpath{
  \circsize=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/spdtcircsize}%
  \pgfextractx{\spdtright}{\northeast}%
  \pgfextracty{\spdtup}{\northeast}%
  \pgfextractx{\spdtleft}{\southwest}%
  \pgfextracty{\spdtdown}{\southwest}%
  % compute sin and cos for sloped line
  \pgfscope
    \spdtlen=0.5\spdtup-0.5\spdtdown-\circsize% length
    \pgfmathmultiply{\spdtlen}{\spdtlen}%
    \let\spdtcos=\pgfmathresult% macro
    \spdtlen=\spdtright-\spdtleft-2\circsize%
    \pgfmathparse{sqrt(\spdtlen*\spdtlen+\spdtcos)}
    \let\spdtsin=\pgfmathresult%
    \pgfmathdivide{\spdtlen}{\spdtsin}%
    \global\let\spdtcos=\pgfmathresult%
    \spdtlen=0.5\spdtup-0.5\spdtdown-\circsize%
    \pgfmathdivide{\spdtlen}{\spdtsin}%
    \global\let\spdtsin=\pgfmathresult%
  \endpgfscope
  % draw circles
  \pgfscope
    \pgfpathcircle{\pgfpoint{\spdtleft+\circsize}{\spdtdown+\circsize}}{\circsize}%
    \pgfpathcircle{\pgfpoint{\spdtleft+\circsize}{\spdtup-\circsize}}{\circsize}%
    \pgfpathcircle{\pgfpoint{\spdtright-\circsize}{0.5\spdtup+0.5\spdtdown}}{\circsize}%
    \pgfusepath{stroke}
  \endpgfscope
  % draw arrow
  \pgfscope
    \pgfsetarrowsend{Triangle[open]}%
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{\spdtright-\circsize-\spdtcos\circsize}{0.5\spdtup+0.5\spdtdown+\spdtsin\circsize}}%
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\spdtleft+\circsize+\spdtcos\circsize}{\spdtup-\circsize-\spdtsin\circsize}}%
    \pgfusepath{stroke}%
    \endpgfscope
  }
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw] (n1) at (1,0) {Testing};
\node[spdt,draw,minimum width=20pt,minimum height=20pt] (n2) [above=10pt of n1] {};
\draw (n2.on) -- +(-0.2,0)
      (n2.off) -- +(-0.2,0)
      (n2.out) -- +(0.2,0);
\node[spdt,draw,minimum width=20pt,minimum height=20pt] (n3) [below=10pt of n1] {X};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Many thanks @JohnKormylo - that is exactly where I want the circles to go; it is `\pgfextractx` that I was missing... In the meantime, I also arrived at a solution, will be posting it here soon.. Cheers!

Comment: @sdaau - I would have placed the circles inside the boundary and defined new anchors (on, off, and out) at the contact points.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, there were several problems I had here.

First of all, I was both drawing circle paths, and circle nodes, to make sure I understand them correctly, so I could use either if need be. Turns out, one has to be careful about the [Size of circle path vs. circle node in \pgfdeclareshape](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/173185/size-of-circle-path-vs-circle-node-in-pgfdeclareshape) - in that `\pgfpathcircle` has a radius argument, but `\pgfnode` via `minumum size` has a diameter argument. Of course, in this case, I only need nodes, as I want to utilize them externally.

Second, I tried calculating height and width of the master node (`\pgfpointdiff{\northeast}{\southwest}`), because I didn't know how to access its anchors; turns out there is a command for it, `\pgfpointanchor` - and `\tikz@fig@name` can be used with it to refer to the master node.

Third, I don't really understand the PGF engine - the way I understood, if you call commands like `\pgfpointanchor`, then you get the results in internal registers `\pgf@x`, `\pgf@y`, which you can then assign to temporary registers `\pgf@xa`, `\pgf@ya` etc. Thus, I thought this would work in obtaining an anchor points coordinates and drawing a circle:

```
{
\pgftransformreset
\pgfpointanchor{\tikz@fig@name}{south west}
\xdef\mycoordinate{\noexpand\pgfpoint{\the\pgf@x}{\the\pgf@y}}
}
\pgfpathcircle{\mycoordinate}{\circsize}
```

... but for some reason it doesn't - `\mycoordinate` turns out wrong. BUT - and this is the weird part - if I stick the entire `\pgfpointanchor{\tikz@fig@name}{south west}` in `\pgfpathcircle` instead of `\mycoordinate`, then the positioning is fine ?!

So, taking all this into account, I arrived at the MWE posted below, which results with this:

[image: test11.png]

The red node `(n2)` is just to test the styling and positions; otherwise `(n3)` to its right is how it would be used.

But there is one more issue - I've noted from somewhere that custom shapes (via `\pgfdeclareshape`) should use only PGF primitives, not TikZ drawing commands - but I have to use `\draw`, so I can easily specify an arrow tip, and so that the line connects the borders of the circular nodes - not their centers. If anyone knows of a solution where the same can be achieved with PGF commands, please post an answer.

Other than that, it seems that this MWE does it for me:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}

\makeatletter
\pgfkeys{/tikz/.cd,
  mycircsize/.store in=\circsize,
  mycircsize=0.2cm
}
\pgfdeclareshape{spdt}{
  \inheritsavedanchors[from={rectangle}]
  \inheritbackgroundpath[from={rectangle}]
  \inheritanchorborder[from={rectangle}]
  \foreach \x in {center,north,north east,north west,south,south east,south west,east,west}{
    \inheritanchor[from={rectangle}]{\x}
  }
%   \backgroundpath{
  \foregroundpath{
    \pgfkeys{/pgf/minimum size = \circsize}
    \pgfset{inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt}
    % draw connector nodes
    \southwest
    \pgfpathcircle{\southwest}{0.5*\circsize}% just a test
    {
    \pgftransformshift{\southwest}
    \pgfnode{circle}{center}{}{\tikz@fig@name-c1}{\pgfusepath{draw}}
    %\pgfusepath{draw}
    }
    {
    \pgftransformshift{\pgfpointanchor{\tikz@fig@name}{north west}}
    \pgfnode{circle}{center}{}{\tikz@fig@name-c2}{\pgfusepath{draw}}
    }
    {
    \pgftransformshift{\pgfpointanchor{\tikz@fig@name}{east}}
    \pgfnode{circle}{center}{}{\tikz@fig@name-c3}{\pgfusepath{draw}}
    }
    % draw switch arrow line
    % with PGF primitives, line goes from center of nodes, not borders
    %\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpointanchor{\tikz@fig@name}{east}}
    %\pgfpathlineto{\pgfpointanchor{\tikz@fig@name}{north west}}
    % so using a TikZ draw command:
    \draw[-open triangle 60] (\tikz@fig@name-c3) -- (\tikz@fig@name-c2);

  }
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw] (n1) at (1,0) {Testing};
\node[spdt,draw=red,line width=2pt,minimum width=20pt,minimum height=20pt] (n2) [above=10pt of n1] {X};
\node[spdt,minimum width=20pt,minimum height=20pt] (n3) [right=40pt of n2] {};

\draw (n1.west) -- ++(-15pt,0) |- (n2-c1);
\draw (n1.east) -- ++(15pt,0) |- (n2-c3);

\draw (n1.east) -- (n3-c3|-n1.east) -- ++(15pt,0) |- (n3-c3);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```